# Align search bar to right inside flex-container

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

**Scenario :**

- Trying to create a navigation bar using flex box,
- and I would like the search bar to be **positioned to the right**, 
  but
  **`justify-self` won't work??**

I'm new to this and it's so frustrating
   to not get something that should be so simple, please someone tell me
   where I'm going wrong!

```css
/* Navigation Bar */

nav {
 display: flex;
 background: var(--navbar);
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav-list > li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0px 25px;
}

.nav-list > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: var(--navlink)
}

.nav-list > li > a:hover {
 color: var(--navhover)
}

.search-bar {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 margin: 12px;
 padding: 8px;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: none;
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
   <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Log In</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Openings</a></li>
  </ul>
 <form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">
 </form>
</nav>
```

Comment: try adding the class 'float-right' to the <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">

Comment: @charlotte-rushen - if an answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so the issue can be closed

Answer (score 0):

In CSS add `justify-content: space-between;` rule to the `nav` element.

```css
nav {
 display: flex;
 background: var(--navbar);
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 10px 0;
        justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-list > li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0px 25px;
}

.nav-list > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: var(--navlink)
}

.nav-list > li > a:hover {
 color: var(--navhover)
}

.search-bar {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 margin: 12px;
 padding: 8px;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: none;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Log In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Openings</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">
  </form>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flex approach :**

- If you want to adjust using `flex properties`, then the **`space-between`** is the solution,
- @David has submitted answer for this case.

**Margin-left Approach :**

- we can adjust margin on the form containing the search field, as it's the last child. 

  So, we can achieve desired result by 
  providing **`margin-left: auto`** to form.

  > **nav > form {
  >       margin-left: auto;
  >   }**

```css
nav {
 display: flex;
 background: var(--navbar);
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

nav > form {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-list > li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0px 25px;
}

.nav-list > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: var(--navlink)
}

.nav-list > li > a:hover {
 color: var(--navhover)
}

.search-bar {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 margin: 12px;
 padding: 8px;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: none;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
   <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Log In</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Openings</a></li>
  </ul>
 <form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">
 </form>
</nav>
```

**Flex-grow Approach :**

- we can adjust `flex-grow` property on the ul (its div before the form element in DOM), so providing **`flex-grow`** would take up the space left after form element has takes space as it needs.

  > **ul {
  >       flex-grow: 1;
  >   }**

```css
nav {
 display: flex;
 background: var(--navbar);
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

ul {
 flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav-list > li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0px 25px;
}

.nav-list > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: var(--navlink)
}

.nav-list > li > a:hover {
 color: var(--navhover)
}

.search-bar {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 margin: 12px;
 padding: 8px;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: none;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
   <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Log In</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Openings</a></li>
  </ul>
 <form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">
 </form>
</nav>
```

Hope, it helps.

Thank you.